# T-SQL query to find jobs and tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the sql server agent jobs that operate upon a particular table. For ex: 
I have a table called TAB1 which is updated daily by a job called SAJ1. I need a query to extract this information.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: https://sufianrashid.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/get-all-job-steps-in-sql-server/

Comment: SAJ1 has direct queries operating on TAB1 or does SAJ1 calls an SSIS job  ?

Comment: @PrabhatG: SAJ1 has direct queries which may actually be calling some stored procedures or may be have t sql queries operating on TAB1.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this select if the job step in T-SQL then it will find the text what you will declare as table name.

```
use msdb
Declare @table_name varchar(50)

set  @table_name='Test'

select j.name,js.command from dbo.sysjobs j
inner join
dbo.sysjobsteps js
on j.job_id=js.job_id
where command like '%'+@table_name+'%'
```

Comment: It works only if I have defined my sql queries in job. What if I am calling a SSIS job in which I have sql queries ?

Comment: The dtsx packages not stored in the job only a parameters. You need to open the dtsx file to find out or the "documentation".

Answer (score 0):

One of the options available is the table msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps that enlists all the jobs and their steps. You can go into the Command column of the output and look for required information.

select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps;